# Falcon server with SSL stops working after some hours/days

Tags: python, ssl, wsgi, falconframework

I set up a very basic Python API server with `falcon` along the example given in the [documentation](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/quickstart.html). And it seems to work just fine.

Now I extended the code to support HTTPS requests using SSL certificates

```
import ssl

httpd = simple_server.make_server('', 8000, app)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(
        httpd.socket, server_side=True,
        certfile='cert.pem',
        keyfile='key.pem')
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And again, it seems to work and HTTPS requests are served perfectly fine...in the beginning.

However, after a while -- maybe a few hours or 1-2 days (no heavy load during testing) -- the server hangs and no longer accepts any requests. Not even with Telnet I can make any kind of connection. The server script doesn't show any errors, and Ubuntu tells me that some process is still listening on this port.

Where do I go from here? I don't even know how to troubleshoot. With the basic HTTP server, I haven't experienced any issues so far

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without more detail. It could be a bug in the framework, or an issue with your environment. That being said, the simple web server is for development. Use something else for production setup: https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/tutorial.html#hosting-your-app

Comment: @Selcuk actually had it first running with `gunicorn` but couldn't figure out how to get that working with my SSL certificates. `simple_server` was the first working alternative for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the above comments, `wsgiref`'s `simple_server` isn't really suitable for production.

Assuming your application is contained in `app.py`, and you installed `gunicorn` into your current Python (virtual) environment, you can run your application with TLS as:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:443 --workers 8 --certfile /path/to/your/cert/cert.pem --key=/pat/to/your/cert/privkey.pem --access-logfile - app:app
```

(You should of course tune the number of workers, threads, etc according to your application's needs.)

Comment: Yes, I switched back to gunicorn, now with https, and haven't had any issues since then